# User can post comment only after login in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm coding a news website,I want the user can submit the comment of the news only after they have logged in,if not,the website will return to login.html.

Now I have made it that only the user who have logged in can submit a comment,**the issue is** once I log off and submit a comment the error says:

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10fed10b8>>": "NewsComments.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance.
```

Note:I have rewrote the User models and rename it UserProfile .It works very well.

Here is my news/views.py:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = News.objects.get(id=news_pk)
    title = news.title
    author = news.author_name
    add_time = news.add_time
    content = news.content
    category = news.category
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))

    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news)

    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and comment_form.is_valid():
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")
        comment = NewsComments(user=request.user, comments=comments, news=news)
        comment.save()

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'add_time': add_time,
        'content': content,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form
    })
```

Here is my news.detail.html

```
            <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5>评论 <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></h5></label>
                    <textarea id="js-pl-textarea" class="form-control" rows="4"
                              placeholder="我就想说..." name="comment"></textarea>
                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id='js-pl-submit' class="btn btn-danger comment-submit-button" value='Submit'>

                        </input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
path('-<int:news_pk>', newsDetailView, name="news_detail"),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use djangos [login-required-decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

```
@login_required
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    ...
```

---

EDIT to expand the idea from my comments.

You could have two views, one with the `login_required` decorator. (You could also use [class-based-views (CBV)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) if you prefer)

```
def view_news_details(request, news_pk):
    ...

@login_required
def post_comments(request, news_pk):
    ...
```

Each view would have their own url:

```
url(r'^(?P<news_pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.view_news_details, name='view-details'),
url(r'^(?P<news_pk>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.post_comments, name='comment'),
```

Then you can have **only one** template but with conditional rendering. This template will be rendered by the view `views.view_news_details`, but the form will send its data to the other view (note the forms `action` attribute).

```
... display the news details here ...

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'comment' news_instance.pk %}">
        ... here goes the content of the form ...
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks!But if I use it,people even can't see the datail_news page before the login ,but what I want is that,they can read the news without login ,but if they want to comment ,they need to login.Could you give me more advise?Thank you so much!

Comment: You could make the comments section a form which posts to another view `<form method="POST" action="/your/other/view/">`. This second view can have the decorator.

Comment: And in your template you could use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` to render the comments form only for logged in users

Comment: So do I need add another url if I make another view?Or could you help make your answer more directly ? ； )Thank you so  much!

Comment: Add the `login_required` decorator to the view will prevent the user from visiting the `newsDetailsView` actually, therefore this is not what @William wants. The user even being anonymous should see the view, but needs a to be authenticated to post any comment

Comment: @William I modified my answer to include code examples.

Comment: @Lemayzeur I modified my answer to include code examples.

Comment: Awesome @Ralf,  It will work, but why have two views while a view can do it. from my point of view, the idea is to let a user enter the view, but prevent him from posting any comment without being authenticated. It's up to you **William**, this answer will work (Two views), and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994203/5644965) just bellow will also work, as I said, it's up to you,to what's better for your code

Comment: @Lemayzeur maybe its my strive for semantic separation that produces these kind of designs, where each view has one specific purpose and authentication/authorization is done at the top of the view (through decorators or mixins).

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the user to your `login view` before let him submit any data in your views.py :

```
# Codes here 

if request.method == 'POST': # We separe those two "if statements", because
    # We want to redirect the user to login even if the form is not valid, User can bypass your security concern

    # For Django < 2.0, use it with () if request.user.is_authenticated():
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login_url_name") # Or HttpResponseRedirect("login_url")
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")

        # Rest of codes
```

**Important**
In your template, give access to the form to **only authenticated users**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5>评论 <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></h5></label>
        <textarea id="js-pl-textarea" class="form-control" rows="4"
                          placeholder="我就想说..." name="comment"></textarea>
        <div class="text-center mt-3">
            <input type="submit" id='js-pl-submit' class="btn btn-danger comment-submit-button" value='Submit' />
         </div>
   </div>
</form>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the requested user is logged-in or not by `user.is_authenticated()` method, which returns a boolean value.

Try the following snippet,

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    # code

    if request.method == 'POST' and comment_form.is_valid():
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponse("Please do login")
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")
        comment = NewsComments(user=request.user, comments=comments, news=news)
        comment.save()

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'add_time': add_time,
        'content': content,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form
    })
```